# After displaying and dismissing the Modal View Controller UIImagePickerController my Cocos2d iPhone app doesn't see multiple touches anymore

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller, multi-touch

I have an app where I display the photo chooser (UIImagePickerController) but after the user dismisses it only single touches are working. And I think I know the root of the issue, but I don't know how to solve it... Before I show the modal dialog the stack during a touch is as follows:

```
...
#3  0x00074de0 in -[EAGLView touchesBegan:withEvent:] at EAGLView.m:289
#4  0x30910f33 in -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:]
...
```

But after showing and then removing the modal dialog the stack has these two mysterious forwardMethod2 calls:

```
...
#3  0x00074de0 in -[EAGLView touchesBegan:withEvent:] at EAGLView.m:289
#4  0x3098dc95 in forwardMethod2
#5  0x3098dc95 in forwardMethod2
#6  0x30910f33 in -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:]
...
```

Here is the code I use to display and remove the UIImagePickerController:
Notes:
 1. pickerViewController is a member of this class that extends UIViewController)
 2. Director is from Cocos2D and contains only a single view attached directly in the root window called openGLView, which is why I made a UIViewController to house my image picker.

```
-(void)choosePhoto: (id)sender{
    UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = pickerViewController.imagePickerController;
    imagePickerController.delegate = self;
    imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    imagePickerController.allowsImageEditing = YES;

    UIView *theView = [[Director sharedDirector] openGLView];
    UIView *pickerViewControllerView = pickerViewController.view;
    [theView addSubview:pickerViewControllerView];
    [pickerViewController presentModalViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES];
}
```

And the code to dismiss the dialog:

```
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)imagePickerController
{
    // Dismiss the image selection
    [pickerViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [pickerViewController.view removeFromSuperview];

    // HERE... IS THERE MORE WORK TO BE DONE TO COMPLETELY REMOVE THE PICKER VIEW????
}
```

There must be something I'm missing in cleaning up the picker view... Help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: are you sure you need to do the addSubView?  I don't think that's necessary, and I'd try removing it to see if it's causing the strange behavior.

Comment: Yeah, taking that part out never shows the dialog. Because "self" isn't a viewController and otherwise my app doesn't use ViewControllers for anything, I have to make one and add it' view to my existing view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After investigating the view hierarchy from the root window down I have found that after dismissing the Photo chooser that my viewController's view was getting added as a child under a UITransitionView so the solution is to remove the superview of my viewController's view instead:

```
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)imagePickerController
{
    // Dismiss the image selection
    [pickerViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [pickerViewController.view.superview removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: Had that problem to and your solution fixed it. Been scratching my head for ages.

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed that CJ Hanson's solution works for me on iPhones:

```
[pickerViewController.view.superview removeFromSuperview];
```

but not on iPads. The normal way:

```
[pickerViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
```

works on the iPad. I just call both at the moment and it seems to work ok:

```
[pickerViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
[pickerViewController.view.superview removeFromSuperview];
```

Maybe someone with more knowledge can clarify why this is needed?